# Ho do I write an .htaccess redirect for a directory containing an ellipsis

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Some how I had an invalid directory indexed in Google, and because of some dynamic relative links I now have 2500 "missing" pages indexed.  I'm trying to use an .htaccess 301 redirect to correct the problem but I can't seem to get it to work.  I need to redirect `www.domain.com/shop/pc/.../pc/filename.asp` to `www.domain.com/shop/pc/filename.asp`.

The rule I have written that doesn't want to work is `RewriteRule ^shop/pc/\.\.\./pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure it is 3 ASCII periods (`.`'s) or the unicode ellipsis (`…`)?

Comment: Deleted my last comment. Thought that fixed it but I jumped the gun.

Comment: You're right I believe - it is the unicode ellipsis, not 3 periods.  How would I write that redirect?  I tried:

`RewriteRule ^pc/…/shop/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]` and
`RewriteRule ^pc/&hellip;/shop/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]`

They don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewite uses [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt), so for these Unicode characters (I included the two dot leader as well, since I imagine that is more likely to sneak into a URL than an ellipsis):

```
# U+2026 … \xe2\x80\xa6 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
RewriteRule ^shop/pc/\xe2\x80\xa6/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]

# U+2025 ‥ \xe2\x80\xa5 TWO DOT LEADER
RewriteRule ^shop/pc/\xe2\x80\xa5/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note you may need the [B] flag ([see flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)) if the browser is percent-escaping the ellipsis.

Comment: Still no luck.  I tried with and without the B flag.

`RewriteRule ^shop/pc/\xe2\x80\xa6/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,L]`

and

`RewriteRule ^shop/pc/\xe2\x80\xa6/pc/(.*)$ /shop/pc/$1 [R=301,B,L]`

Comment: I know the above mod_rewrite recipe works, so that means we are not targeting the correct characters. What is in your error log? It will tell you exactly what is coming in from the outside.

Comment: Here is an entry from the log. `2014-01-21 00:39:38 208.106.254.53 GET /shop/pc/.../pc/Reprorubber-Combo-Kit-Quick-Dispense-Cartridge-System-Kit-10p4672.htm - - 157.55.32.221 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+bingbot/2.0;++http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) - - www.flexbar.com 200 0 48979 354 718`.   It does appear to be 3 periods here.  However I tried escaping 3 periods to start (See first post) and that didn't work either. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: That certainly appears to be three periods and not a UTF-8 char, so your first recipe with `\.\.\.` should be fine. The issue then is getting mod_rewrite to match, which can be tricky if you have any an Alias or Location getting in the way, as well as the location of your .htaccess file. Can you enable mod_rewrite logging? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog